# Laravel Upload Multiple Images all records with same name and not moved files

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am new in Laravel and I develop a web application where someone can upload a car ad and other users can write comments bellow that. Instead of developing a simple CRUD application I thought about developing also a table that will be related to these ads and will store the photos. Up to this point, I have made the relations, I can show images and I have two problems: The first problem is that not all images are moved to storage/photos folder and the second problem is that all the records in the database have the same name. For example, if I want to upload images 1,2,3 then in the database all the files will have the name 1.

Bellow, you may find the store code. This code stores all the ads and also the images if they exist.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    //
    $this->validate($request, [
        'name' => 'required',
        'cc' => 'required',
        'desc' => 'required',
        'date' => 'required'
    ]);
    $ad = new Ad;

    $ad->name = $request->input('name');
    $ad->cc = $request->input('cc');
    $ad->desc = $request->input('desc');
    $ad->date = $request->input('date');
    $ad->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $ad->save();

    if ($request->hasFile('photos')) {
        $allowedfileExtension = ['pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'docx'];
        $files = $request->file('photos');
        foreach ($files as $file) {
            $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
            //$file->move('storage/photos', $filename); 
            $check = in_array($extension, $allowedfileExtension);

            if ($check) { 
                foreach ($request->photos as $photo) {
                    $photo->move('storage/photos', $filename); 
                    $img = new AdsPhoto;
                    $img->ad_id = $ad->id;
                    $img->filename = $filename;
                    $img->save();
                }
                return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'ad + image created');
            } else {
                echo '<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>Warning!</strong> Sorry Only Upload png , jpg , doc</div>';
            }
        }
    }
    return redirect('/home')->with('success','ad created');
}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1st mistake, you did looping twice

2nd mistake (you might not realize this) you didnt merge the filename and extension, this will cause an issue when you retrieving the image in blade

therefore correction on your code plus comment to explain it

```
if ($request->hasFile('photos')) {
    $allowedfileExtension = ['pdf', 'jpg', 'png', 'docx'];
    $files = $request->file('photos');
    foreach ($files as $file) {
        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
        //$file->move('storage/photos', $filename); 
        $check = in_array($extension, $allowedfileExtension);
        $fullpath = $filename . '.' . $extension ; // adding full path

        if ($check) { 
            // removing 2nd loop
           $file->move('storage/photos', $fullpath); // you should include extension here for retrieving in blade later
           $img = new AdsPhoto;
           $img->ad_id = $ad->id;
           $img->filename = $filename;
           $img->save();
        }

        } else {
            echo '<div class="alert alert-warning"><strong>Warning!</strong> Sorry Only Upload png , jpg , doc</div>';
        }
    }
    return redirect('/home')->with('success', 'ad + image created');
}
```

Comment: First of all, Ghiffari thank you for your answer. With your code, if I select multiple files, then again only one is moved to photos folder. Also, the problem now is that only one record is being saved to the table where previously all the records were saved but they had the same filename

Comment: @EdwardCooper , can you dd($request->file('photos')  and Put it on pastebin

Comment: @EdwardCooper and are you sure you already copy paste my entire code above?

Comment: I want to really thank you for your answer. When I dd then everything is fine. I copied-pasted your code and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation, if you want to put your file on storage instead of on public folder you need to put these few lines of code as below in the your controller class

```
<?php
...
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
...
class YourController extends Controller{
...
// Automatically generate a unique ID for file name...
Storage::putFile('photos', new File('/path/to/photo'));
...
}
```

This command will put your file into storage folder

Comment: thank you for your answer. The problem is that only one file is being moved if I select multiple files.

Comment: did you loop through your files?